# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference error in partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference error
```

I am getting this error in a partial view.

```
loginUserExists = Membership.ValidateUser(UserNameLogin, PasswordUserLogin);
if (loginUserExists==false)
{
    return;
}
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserNameLogin, true);
```

This is my partial view which produces the error.

```
@*This is where the error happens*@
**@if (!Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)**
{
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("LoginForm", "Home")">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("RegisterForm", "Home")">Register</a></li>
}
else
{

    <li><a href="@Url.Action("LoginForm", "Home")">Logout</a></li>
    if (Model.FirstName != null)
    {
        <li><label id="labUserName">@Model.FirstName</label></li>
    }
}
```

The partial view is nested in the Layout page.

Insight perhaps as to why I get this and how to overcome it?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Request.IsAuthenticated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.isauthenticated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
@if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // ...
}
```